# TCP window size is set to zero by the server during a three way handshake

Tags: linux, tcp

Our clients occasionally fail to connect to our web server (CentOS 6.5, Kernel 2.6.32-504.1.3.el6.x86_64, Apache 2.4.x). The captured packets show that the server set the window size to zero during the three way handshake and then reset the connection (as shown in the screenshot below). I would love to know

1) What condition(s) would cause such an issue?

2) Is there a way to **proactively** monitor it? If the reason is that the kernel run out of some kind of memory, is there a way to monitor its usage & upper bound?

3) Is there any tuning that can be done?

Many thanks in advance.

[image: Packet Capture]

Comment: It won't be a resource issue. Possibly the server has set its socket receive buffer size to zero for some reason, but the following RST suggests it might be some kind of firewall defence.

Comment: Many thanks EJP. I should have mentioned this in my original post. We have a test machine that has a static IP and sits in the same data center as the web server. It sends hundreds of requests to the web server every minute and runs into the same issue occasionally. The CPU & Memory utilization of the web server looks normal. The max # of concurrent/established TCP connections is less than 200. Do you still think it might have something to do with firewall? If so, any suggestion on how to gather more evidence? Thanks again!

Comment: Sorry no. Maybe @DavidSchwartz has some idea about this.

Comment: Resource exhaustion would be my guess.  Maybe track open socket count?  Possibly `/proc/sys/net/core/rmem_{default,max}` are too small?

Comment: Many thanks Jason for your reply. Here are the two values you asked: net.core.rmem_max = 4194304 & net.core.rmem_default = 124928. If the reason was that rmem was used up, is there a metric/counter that tracks that?